# Copy select items from one folder to a new folder

Tags: powershell, recursion, powershell-4.0, get-childitem, copy-item

I am getting all wav files in the past 24 hours from one folder and putting them in another folder. I swear this worked for me a bit ago and wanted to add in some more conditional statements but now it is working. It is not creating a new folder for 'NewSounds' it is just creating a blank document named that, and I am stumped. Also any tips on best place to put a pipeline for only selecting the -Top 10 results once filtered down from the .wav files recently added??

```
$scriptPath = "/Users/robertunderwood/Splice/sounds/"
$Destination = "/Users/robertunderwood/NewSounds"
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.wav

    foreach($file in $fileNames){
        if ($file.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)){   
            Write-Host $file.Name                                 
            Copy-Item $file -Destination $Destination
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not test for the folder then create it?

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment...

You can always just create the folder and copy to it:

```
$scriptPath = "/Users/robertunderwood/Splice/sounds/"
$Destination = "/Users/robertunderwood/NewSounds"
Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Filter "*.wav" -Recurse | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date } |
    Select-Object -First 10 | ForEach-Object -Begin {
        if (-not(Test-Path -Path $Destination -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Container | Out-Null
        }
    } -Process {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination
    }
```

Swapped your `if` statement to `Where-Object` to streamline the process. Also selected the top (*first*) 10 files found to copy.

You're expecting `Copy-Item` to create the folder and copy the files for you and that's where your issue occurs. `Copy-Item` can in fact create the folder first, then recursively copy to it when providing the `-Recurse` switch but, not when it's piped to it (`... | Copy-Item`); this includes even providing the `-Force` switch. So the alternative is to use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet to create the folder first (*in your *Begin* block*), then copy to it. *You can honestly create it whenever, wherever, using other methods, as long as it's not before the actual copying.*

Comment: I would do `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date` to set the reference date to midnight. Otherwise, it depends on the time of day you run this code.

Comment: Sweet! Any chance you could explain what I was messing up in my code? It was only outputting blank documents when I would run it.

Comment: @robertuxo, see my edit for a better explanation. Also added Theo's suggestion.